# Initializing python class with list/array

Tags: python, class, initialization

I can't initialize a class with a list

This is for a gradient descent problem, I want to create an object with a list (weights).

I have tried using weights = None and changing the type from array to list but i keep on getting "numpy.ndarray object not callable" regardless.

the array y in estimate has been defined, I have just excluded it from here.

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__ (self,  weights = None):
        self.weights = weights 
        self.estimate = self.estimate()
        self.loss = self.loss()
        self.cost = self.cost()
        self.gradient = self.gradient()

    def estimate(self):
        estimate = np.dot(y, self.weights)
        return estimate

    def loss(self):
        loss = (self.estimate - target)
        return loss

    def cost(self):
        cost = np.sum(self.loss **2)

    def gradient(self):
        gradient = np.dot(yTrans, self.loss)
        return gradient

    def gradient_descent(self):

        alpha = 0.0001
        self.weights = self.weights - alpha * self.gradient
        return weights

w = [10, 14, 15, 10, 5]
k = Point(w)
k.weights()
```

I expect `k.gradient()` to return an array of weights but i can't even initialise the class

Comment: How about ? 
instance = Point(weights=[10, 14, 15, 10, 5])
print(instance.weights)

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but why did the way I did it not work? with w = [,,] and instance = Point(w)

Comment: It doesn't work because you use keyword arguments instead of positional arguments
you __init__ should be like def __init__(self, weights) instead of def __init__(self, weights=None) if you want to use code like in your example. PS If my answer was helpful for you, please mark it as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` doesn't work in the way you want, because you used keyword arguments instead of positional arguments in your `__init__` method, it should be like `def __init__(self, weights)` instead of `def __init__(self, weights=None)`

How about this **solution**?

```
point = Point(weights=[10, 14, 15, 10, 5])
print(point.weights)
```

Also, you can define the list as a variable like this:

```
weights=[10, 14, 15, 10, 5]
point = Point(weights=weights)
print(point.weights)
```

**Another solution** If you change your `__init__` like `def __init__(self, weights)`you will be able to create the instance in new way, because now your argument in `__init__` will be positional instead of keyword:

```
point = Point([10, 14, 15, 10, 5])
print(point.weights)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call an array as a function. You need to try it the following way

```
w = [10, 14, 15, 10, 5]
k = Point(w)
print(k.weights)
```

when we have `()` then it becomes a callable, generally we use `()` for functions and classes. We dont use `()` for datatypes such as `int, str, float, list` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that weights was never a function, but k.estimate works while k.estimate() does not eventhough estimate is a method. Does this only apply to arrays?

Comment: actually you are assigning a function to the variable self.estimate, so the variable self.estimate now holds a function. Thats the reason why self.estimate works with `()`.

Comment: it applies not only to list, to all python data types such as `int, str, float, list, tuple, dict, set`